# How to retain comments even after generating apk file

Tags: html, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Hi I am using sencha touch 2 framework and i need to retain comments in the code even after building apk file using the following command "sencha app build native".

When i get app.js after building apk file it contains all code apart from whatever i commented in code. So is there any tool or configuration or option to retain comments in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Not with sencha command, you would have to build your apk in eclipse, sencha does offer an IDE plugin for eclipse...  it doesnt take long to do and you can figure it out off of this tutorial: http://andidog.de/blog/2012/06/packaging-a-sencha-touch-2-application-with-phonegap-for-android/

Comment: Thanks for ur reply .The thing is that i want to retain my commented code even after building apk file. Right now i am using jetbrains webstorm ide to develop sencha application. So is there any tool which i integrate with jetbrains and retain commented code after building my apk file.